# Filtering a large sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large (60,000 x 60,000) symmetric document similarity matrix stored in the scipy sparse csr_matrix format.

I want to find the indices of all values that are above a certain value. In other words, all the document pairs that have a similarity score greater than a certain value.

When I try something like

```
matrix > 0.9
```

my ipython kernel crashes.

I'm new to scipy and numpy, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the error message that ipython crashes with please?

Comment: It's just a dialog box saying something along the lines of "The kernel has stopped and will be restarted". Pretty sure it's due to the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I would try performing the operation on a smaller set of data 
I just tried

```
In [22]: import scipy.sparse as sps
In [23]: m = sps.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(100,100))

In [24]: m
Out[24]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [25]: m > .5
Out[25]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 5028 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

So that seemed to work. Maybe your matrix is too big / dense. Did you build scipy yourself? Perhaps there is a build error causing it to crash.

What is your OS / version of python / version of scipy?

```
import scipy
scipy.__version__
```

Comment: My scipy version is 0.14.1. Yes, the matrix is very big and is quite dense. There are ~3,000,000,000 non-zero entries. I believe that is the issue. I'm wondering if there are any tricks to get around this (perhaps some way to efficiently round down very small entries to zero?)

Comment: Thats a good idea, but I don't know how to do it off hand. I would look into trying to set a precision flag. How are you constructing the matrix? Maybe you could zero some data before it goes into it?